# woocommerce custom toggle on loop

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i am beginner at php and jquery. I am trying to do toggle button when click "view button" on woocomemerce archive loop. I do this

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item','select_variation_popup', 15);

function select_variation_popup() {
    
global $product;
    
    if ($product->is_type('variable') && $product->is_in_stock())
     {
         echo '<button type="button" id="variation-toggle" >View Detais</button>';
        ?> <style> button#variation-toggle {
    width: 100% !important;
    font-weight:bold;
} 
form.variations_form.cart {
    display:none;
}
</style> <?php
    }
}
```

For jquery showing i do

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'toggle_variable');
function toggle_variable() {
 ?> 
    <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#variation-toggle").click(function () {
        $("form.variations_form.cart").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

My problem is when i click on one product is toggle variation_form for all products. How i can restrict showing variation form to be at only one?

Any help will be appreciated!!!
Thanks!

Comment: IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document, and by creating an element with a static ID inside a loop, you are violating that basic rule already.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @CBroe. it will be possible to reacreate snippets above and include in id something by product like id or name..
And rewrite jquery snippet like told to second class to catch this id or name?
Thanks you for time!

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do. But as CBroe said you're assigning multiple objects to the same ID, if you want to apply the same styling and Onclick event to the buttons use a class instead. Could you provide further clarification on what you're hoping to achieve and what the result you're currently getting is?

Comment: Instead of trying to create unique IDs, it is often a better idea to distance yourself a bit from always selecting elements _by_ ID - that is by far not the only method that exists to select elements. Start by writing your JS code so that it selects the elements to bind to via a common _class_, and then use the relationship elements have in the DOM, if you need to navigate from the _current_ element you are handling inside your click handler. to some other element that is in relation to it (parent, sibling, etc.)

Comment: I want when click button "view more" to toggle variation form. In photo example i have already clicked first button. I want variation form to appear once per clicking button.

[link](https://prnt.sc/voh74t)

Comment: Thanks for answers!

Comment: Since you're using the selector `form.variations_form.cart` in your toggle() call. It is changing the status of all the forms that match your selector. As I don't know how your HTML is structured you could try `$(this).closest("form.variations_form.cart").toggle();` or failing that use the Product ID to create a unique ID for each button and form, extract that ID on button press and then toggle the relevant form. You should also look at `wp_enqueue_style` and `wp_enqueue_script` for including your jQuery and CSS.

Comment: I tried both variant, but unfortunatelly without success :(
I tried to get product id and include in loop, but jquery doesnt worked

`global $product; <?php echo esc_attr( $product->get_id() ); ?>`
this is code i used